# Convert each row of CSV file to separate XML files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I want to convert each row of CSV into separate Xml file.

CSV

```
Number;Name;City
1;Alvin;Spain
2;Carol;USA
3;John;Japan
```

XML (3 files)

xml1:

```
<TopElement>
  <Item>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Name>Alvin</Name>
    <City>Spain</City>
  </Item>
</TopElement>
```

xml2:

```
<TopElement>
  <Item>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Name>Carol</Name>
    <City>USA</City>
  </Item>
</TopElement>
```

xml3.. so on..

So far I only found this solution, which output all in same file

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\csv.txt");

string[] headers = lines[0].Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray();

var xml = new XElement("TopElement",
           lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0).Select(line => new XElement("Item",
              line.Split(';')
                  .Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))));

xml.Save(@"C:\Users\output.xml");
```

Anyone please help me how to modify above code probably by adding "For" loop.

Comment: This is the problem when you learn to code by copy/paste. When it comes time to make changes, you need to get others to write code you can copy/paste to make those changes. It's much better if you actually learn to read and understand the code yourself, so that when you need to change it you can do so yourself.

Comment: User `for` loop with counter starting with `1` and loop thru `lines`. and for each line then you create xml and save it to file.

Comment: Don't you just need to change the last line to NOT have a fixed file name ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `for` statement to loop through the CSV file lines and then create an XML file for each line. Maybe something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= csv_total_lines; i++)
        {
            string filename = string.Format(@"C:\Users\Public\file{0}.xml", i.ToString());
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Top Element");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Item");
            writer.WriteElementString("Number", i.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("Name", "Alvin");
            writer.WriteElementString("City", "Spain");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
```

You also need System.Xml library.